# PHP DateTime Invalid Auction end date

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have coded a Laravel 5 Auction Bid Script for Products.

If I want to create a new Product I can enter the "End Date" for the Auction, but I get always this Error:

> "Invalid end date"

I have tried all Date variants but none have worked.

My code for the Auction End Date in ProductController:

```
if (validateDate($request->end_date)) {
          $end_date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d\TH:i',$request->end_date);
          $now = date('Y-m-d\TH:i');
          $end_date1 =  date_format($end_date,'Y-m-d\TH:i');
          if ($end_date1 < $now) {
            session()->flash('errormessage','Invalid end date');
            return redirect()->back()->withInput();
          }
```

I am entering the Date and Clock in this format:

> End Date and time
>
> 2017-10-22\15:00

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `\T` in your format means you're expecting a *literal* "T" instead of the *format* "T" (timezone abbreviation). So you need to enter your date as "2017-10-22T15:00"

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are using Mysql

if column type is `datetime` then it must be

```
2017-09-24 05:03:24
```

if column type is `date` then it must be

```
2017-09-24
```

if you are using mysql then your date format is invalid

Answer (score 0):

If you have created migration for end date like this

```
$table->dateTime('end_date');
```

then you need to create date from this format:

```
$end_date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s',$request->end_date);
```

This will give you

> 2017-10-22 15:00:00

If you have created migration for end date like this:

```
$table->dateTimeTz('end_date');
```

then use this format

```
$end_date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-dTH:i:s',$request->end_date);
```

This will give you end_date like this

> 2017-10-22T15:00:00

Answer (score 0):

Thanks All for the Help!

Thats Correct:

> 2017-10-22T15:00